# Bad Ivy file - Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: xml, ant, publish, ivy

Here is my case: I have set up a simple Ant project with an Ivy task for publishing an artifact to a local repository. When I run tha ant script, I see the following error:

```
build.xml: impossible to publish artifacts for my.company#myproject;1.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: bad ivy file for my.company#myproject;1.0: C:\Users\user\Documents\test\myproject\build\myproject.jar: java.text.ParseException: [[Fatal Error] myproject.jar:1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog. in file:/C:/Users/user/Documents/test/myproject/build/myproject.jar
]
```

Now, I've read the internet about this issue and I found the common explanation that this "No content allowed in prolog" error is seen when there is a symbol, preceding the

```
"<?xml version ... ?>"
```

declaration. Well, I don't have ANYTHING before that in my ivy file. I searched it with notepad++, turning on the "Show all characters" option.. nothing.
Please, is there anyone who has faced this issue?
Here are my files:

ivy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="my.company" module="myproject" />
    <publications>
        <artifact name="myproject" type="jar"/>
    </publications>
    <dependencies>
        ...
        some list of dependencies
        ...
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Build.xml target:

```
<target name="publish">
    <ivy:publish resolver="local" revision="1.0" organisation="my.company" module="myproject" overwrite="true">
       <artifacts pattern="${basedir}/build/myproject.jar" />
    </ivy:publish>
</target>
```

Thanks!

Comment: your ivy file is not the culprit. Some XML parser tries to parse `myproject.jar` which obviously does not succeed. Maybe your `<artifacts>` element has wrong syntax?

Comment: Indeed if I change the artifact to  <artifacts pattern="${basedir}/build/[artifact].[ext]" /> then the error is: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ivy file not found in cache for my.company#myproject;1.0!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that revision="1.0" has to be a part of the ivysettings.xml file not in the publish task.